How do I get speech-to-text to produce a £
I read What is the list of commands to dictate punctuation, capitalization and line breaks?, and it says the command "pound sign" will produce a # for UK English which it does.
How do I get a £ instead?
My system language is English UK.

Did you try including the word sterling?

@wbogacz yes pound sterling also gbp, great british pound

US vs International usage
The name "pound sign" should only produce the character "#" if you use US English TTS.
Internationally, the "#" is called "number sign", "hash", or something else.
Even the Unicode Consortium decided it should be called "Number sign".
In general "£" is known internationally as "pound" or "pund sign".

System language vs Input language

Your system language does not decide your TTS language just like it doesn't change your keyboard layout.

My Samsung phone has 3 keyboard layouts and 2 TTS languages installed. I change between all of those without touching my system language.


Please check your input language settings and install both TTS variants so you can switch between them if needed.

Links:
Wikipedia: Number sign:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign#Names

Wikipedia: Pound Sign:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Pound_sign


Wish I knew what I changed, but I poked around this morning and now I can say 200 pounds and I get £200. but thanks input language was very helpful.
